# Magento: Select the top ordered products

Tags: select, collections, magento

I need a block where i can display my "top sellers" but don't know how i can do the collection select. What "addAttributeToSelect" do i need?

Comment: Try to flesh out your question more.

Comment: http://pastie.org/556430 How can i add an filter "top ten ordered products"

Answer (score 0):

See this thread from the magento forums - addresses your very question:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/14764/P15/

and this post in particular looks good (assuming you are using magento 1.3)

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewreply/156664/